# How to fix header of table and allow data to move vertically and also at same time allow both header and data move vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck with a problem, i am having a table which i made using  tag. The problem is that i have to give a vertical scrollbar at the browser and not at the div. And when i move the vertical scrollbar then only the data of that table should be allowed to move but not the header. And if we move the horizontal scrollbar then both the header and also the data should move. I think i need to use some Java Script or JQuery . But i am new to this designing part so i am not very aware how i am able to do this  please help me out

Comment: depends on how you set this up.  You might need to provide some html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the header at the top while you scroll, give it the css property `position:fixed;`

Here's a quick example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DigitalBiscuits/ymevS/1/

Comment: hi allen n digital can u please give me ur mail id so that i can send my html codes to you, so that u will be able to understand what i want. Please help me as i am new to this JavaScript and i have a deadline to meet.